# PHP Programmatically add a www if no subdomain listed in a string?

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a series of string that could either be:

```
1:   google.com
2:   www.google.com
3:   finance.google.com
```

What I need to do is basically add a www. to any string that doesn't have a subdomain already attached to it.

So in this case, we should add a www. infront of string #1 (google.com) but leave #2 and #3 alone.

What do you think would be the best way to accomplish this?  Some form of REGEX?

Comment: Why were you wanting to do this? I know personally that some sites (generally for misguided reasons) point `http://example.com` and `http://www.example.com/` to different locations.

Comment: Side note: if you're doing this for redirection you'd be better off to use **.htaccess** or **httpd.conf** (assuming apache)

Comment: Are these strings part of a longer string? If so then regex will be best. If not then a simple string manipulation would do the trick and probably be more readable if you don't have anyone that understands regex well.

Comment: after .com / symbol usualy follows, so you can take the string before the first slash and count the dots, if there is less then one, well in your case it will most likely need a www.

Comment: The answers posted so far presume a single part TLD such as '.com'. It will all get a bad result if you are fed a multi-part TLD such as .co.uk. You should take this into consideration and check first for the existence of the 'www', at least.

Comment: I really don t know why all the answer count the number of dots. it is totally wrong, you can have lot of combination...

Comment: What a hilarious series of identical wrong answers. You cannot simply count the dot-separated segments. There are many TLDs which contain multiple dots, **.co.uk** being the most obvious example. If you haven't guessed by now, this is harder than you think it is, and you probably *don't* want to do it. `google.com` and `www.google.com` are *not the same thing*, and the don't have to resolve to the same IP. You cannot safely assume that they point to the same thing, and blinding adding "www" is almost certainly not the solution to whatever your real problem is.

Comment: Basically, what you want to do is have a list of country code TLDs (like `uk`, `ca`, etc) and a list of generic TLDs (like `com`, `org`, `info`, etc). Pop off the characters after the last dot, then if those characters are in the CC TLDs check to see if there are three dots, or if they're in the generic TLDs check to see if there are two dots. If either of those pass, then put a `www.` in front. Otherwise, don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't because there is no specific rules (how many subdomains, for instance you.can.have.lot.of.dots.com ...), and you can't know that www.yourdomain.com is equal to yourdomain.com

Answer (score 0):

You could detect if the 4th character is a dot. Not always going to work, but it will detect the presence of either a 3-letter prefix, or a url for a 3-letter domain name. (such as ksl.com)

```
if (substr($url,4,1)==".")
```

You could also check the first 3 for WWW

```
if (strtolower(substr($url,0,3))=="www")
```

Good Luck

Answer (score -3):

```
$domain = "in.yahoo.com";

$pattern = '/\./';

preg_match_all($pattern, $domain, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

if(count($matches[0])==1){
    $new_domain="www.".$domain;
} else {
    $new_domain=$domain;
}

print $new_domain;
```

Answer (score -4):

Regex, or you could count the dots in this case. If there are two, www. can be added in front. That is assuming you don't use filenames, pages, (sub)domains with extra dots, and so on.

```
<?php
if(substr_count($url, '.') < 2)
{
    $url = "www.".$url;
}
?>
```

Comment: what? you want finance.google.com to become www.finance.google.com?

Comment: "Oh no, why doesn't `bbc.co.uk` redirect to `www.bbc.co.uk`? And why is `google.com` forwarding to `wwwgoogle.com`?"

Comment: > JohnJohnGa, typo in the number. > CanSpice, That's why i wrote "That is assuming you don't use filenames, pages and so on." It works in the examples he gave, but isn't monkeyproof.